# How to read sql table in float format instead of object?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, types

I'm reading a sql table full of stock prices with pandas, but I am having the problem that the prices are object type when using them on my python code. In my sql table i have some #N/A values that I cannot get rid of (I don't want to).

I know that it would be possible to give the prices the float type on my code, but I would like them to be floats when I import them from the sql server.

I tried changing the "," separator and keeping it but i don't get results.

Thanks for your attention

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\db.sqlite3')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT replace(IndexLevel, ',', '.') AS prices, PriceDate FROM IndexLevel",
                  conn, parse_dates="PriceDate")
```

Comment: What are the actual column types in the SQL database schema? Please read [mre] and try to make it possible for others to reproduce the problem exactly.

Comment: Date: TEXT, Ticker: TEXT, IndexLevel: NUMERIC (also tried with INT)

Comment: Have you seen the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) for read_sql? In particular, does the `coerce_float` argument solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't, i tried it but didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your column after extracting it:

```
mapping = {'#N/A': np.nan, ',': '.'}
df['prices2'] = df['prices'].replace(mapping, regex=True).astype(float)
print(df)

# Output
    prices  prices2
0     #N/A      NaN
1  1234,32  1234.32
2  5689,23  5689.23
```

Answer (score 0):

in order for the column to be float type, the values have to be numeric. Thus you'll have to get rid off the N/A values first then convert the column to float.

```
# doesn't have to be 0, can be any value that works for your dataset
df['Price'] = df['Price'].fillna(0)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype('float64')
```

now your column is float

Answer (score 0):

You can convert '#N/A' to null values in pandas. Also, you will need to remove the thousands separator (for example '1,000' to '1000') before converting to float values.

```
import numpy as np

df['prices'] = df['prices'].str.replace(',', '', regex=True).str.replace('#N/A', np.nan).astype('float')
```